# changing the logo of a venue from the API

Tags: foursquare

We're looking for a way to change the venue's logo image through the API. We're able to add pictures to the venue via the `/photos/add` endpoint with the `venueId` parameter, and that seems to work as expected.

However, we're completely stumped about changing the logo of the venue and cannot seem to find the documentation.

Is this achievable?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you the manager of the venue? Have you read https://support.foursquare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201064130-How-to-edit-your-selected-photos-

Comment: Yes, I am the manager of the venue and I have read that article, and that article doesn't answer my question. The question, is whether or not one can upload the *logo* of a venue through the *API*, not the UI. The article you pointed me to only speaks of uploading images to the venue, and not the logo of the venue.

Comment: It's probably a private API. Your best bet is -> https://enterprise.foursquare.com/contact-us